# unable to write an update statement with left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

my update statement works fine with INNER JOIN but gives me error when I replace it with LEFT JOIN. HOw can I achieve left join here ?
I am looking for LEFT JOIN results where if a corresponding rn =2 doesn't exist then I need to update null in the table.

```
with cte as (
select * from 
( select row_number() over(partition by user_id order by loginDate desc) rn,
        min(loginDate) over(partition by user_id) min_date,
        max(loginDate) over(partition by user_id) max_date,
       dau.* from DAILY_Active_user_table dau ) as foo
where rn <= 2
)

update user_agg_activity 
    SET first_login_date = cte.min_date,
        last_login_date  = cte.max_date,
        prev_login_date =  cte.loginDate,
        date_partition = current_date
    from user_agg_activity uac, cte 
    where  cte.user_id = user_agg_activity.user_id;
    --group by uac.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many references to the `user_agg_activity`.  The reference in the `FROM` is entirely different from the reference in the `UPDATE`, so it results in a Cartesian product.  So:

```
update user_agg_activity uac
    SET first_login_date = cte.min_date,
        last_login_date  = cte.max_date,
        prev_login_date =  cte.loginDate,
        date_partition = current_date
    from cte 
    where cte.user_id = uac.user_id;
```

Comment: I am looking to update the prev_login_date as null if there is no corresponding rn=2, this query still doest do that.

Comment: here is the `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=27435941cc97b7a239ec5b00fcde03da`

Comment: @deg . . . I really have no idea what your comment means.  This is fixing the logic in the `update`, not the CTE.